# Gmail/Email To field EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, email-client

Is there a control for android that mimics the autocomplete and "autobox"(like in gmail app where after you select a email it puts the contact into a box and places it in the textbox) for email compose?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot? It's not quite clear what you want.

Comment: I too would like to know how to do this. I believe he is talking about the Gmail app on Android 4.1 or 4.1 where the user turns into a rectangle showing their avatar and name. Clicking on them reveals a delete button.

Answer (score 2):

Are you for looking for something like this:

main.xml

```
<MultiAutoCompleteTextView
 android:id="@+id/compose_to"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:hint="To"
 android:imeOptions="actionNext"
 android:textColor="#000000"
 android:inputType="textEmailAddress|textMultiLine"
 />
```

main.java

```
MultiAutoCompleteTextView to = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.compose_to);

ArrayList<String> addresses = new ArrayList<String>();
addresses.add("temp@gmail.com");
addresses.add("abc@gmail.com");
addresses.add("xyz@gmail.com");
addresses.add("template@gmail.com");

ArrayAdapter<String> autocompAdapter =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, addresses);

to.setAdapter(autocompAdapter);
to.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());
```

[image: Android EditText Autocomplete]

Comment: they seem to be redesigning the site. I have added the actual code now.